# Wrapping container for containers providing diffrent interfaces

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, wrapper, variadic-templates

I want to create universal "wrapper" for stl containers, something like:

```
template<template <typename, typename...> class Container = std::vector >
class ContainerWrapper{
  add();
  size();
  find();
  resize();
  sort(); 
  /**/
}
```

+iterators.
I would want member functions to have different implementations, depending on Container provided methods. Is C++ template system enough to create this? Is this even possible, using only standard (no boost, no messing with preprocessor)?

I know how to do it the hard way - write template specialization for each stl container. But I would want it to work with other containers too, and also i'm looking for more universal way to do it.

Also, what is better here? Inheriting from `Container` or having `Container` as component?

Comment: Regarding the standard containers, they are not designed to be inherited.

Comment: As each `ContainerWrapper` is an unrelated type, why do you want this?  I mean, not every std container can be `resized`.  What happens when passed a `std::set`, and how does that make your solution better than just taking a `std::set` in the first place?  Are you addicted to things being members of a type?  Why not just free functions?  Like `sort(container)`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux As my comment to the answer; they are not designed to be inherited *polymorphically*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I've developed something similar for a project of mine.

I've extracted a full working example (the original code is more complex) to show how to use a method `addVal()` (that call `push_back()`, `push()`, `insert()` or `push_front()`) to add a value to the wrapped container.

This code works (if I remember correctly) for `std::vector`, `std::set`, `std::multiset`, `std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_multiset`, `std::deque`, `std::queue`, `std::priority_queue`, `std::forward_list` and `std::stack`.

Other containers (as `std::array`, by example) may requires different specializations for `cntWrp`.

I don't want explaint every single line of code but, if you have questions, I can try to respond (or, if you prefer, I can give you the link of my github project).

The example

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>

class emptyClass
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct funcType;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct funcType<T, Ts...>
 { using type
      = typename std::conditional<T::result,
         typename T::type, typename funcType<Ts...>::type>::type; };

template <>
struct funcType<>
 { using type = emptyClass; };


#define methodCheck_1(meth)                            \
                                                       \
   class helpMeth_1_##meth {};                         \
                                                       \
   template <typename T, typename A>                   \
   struct isWithMethod_1_##meth                        \
    {                                                  \
      template<typename U>                             \
      static decltype(U().meth(A())) func (U*);        \
                                                       \
      template<typename U>                             \
      static emptyClass func (...);                    \
                                                       \
      static const bool result                         \
         = ! std::is_same<emptyClass,                  \
                decltype(func<T>(nullptr))>::value;    \
                                                       \
      using  type = helpMeth_1_##meth;                 \
    }

methodCheck_1(insert);
methodCheck_1(push);
methodCheck_1(push_back);
methodCheck_1(push_front);

template <typename>
class cntWrp;

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename X, typename ... Xs>
class cntWrp< C<X, Xs...> >
 {
   private:

      using addModeType = typename funcType<
         isWithMethod_1_push_back<C<X, Xs...>, X>,
         isWithMethod_1_insert<C<X, Xs...>, X>,
         isWithMethod_1_push<C<X, Xs...>, X>,
         isWithMethod_1_push_front<C<X, Xs...>, X>>::type;

      static constexpr addModeType  addMode {};

      void addVal (X const & x, helpMeth_1_push_back const)
       { val.push_back(x); }

      void addVal (X const & x, helpMeth_1_push const)
       { val.push(x); }

      void addVal (X const & x, helpMeth_1_insert const)
       { val.insert(x); }

      void addVal (X const & x, helpMeth_1_push_front const)
       { val.push_front(x); }

      void addVal (X const & x, emptyClass const)
       { throw std::runtime_error("cntWr<>::addVal without mode"); }

   public:

      C<X, Xs...> val {};

      cntWrp ()
       { }

      cntWrp (C<X, Xs...> const & v0) : val { v0 }
       { }

      void addVal (X const & x)
       { addVal(x, addMode); }
 };

int main ()
 {
   cntWrp<std::set<int>>  csi;

   csi.addVal(2);
   csi.addVal(7);
   csi.addVal(5);

   std::cout << "set:" << std::endl;

   for ( auto const elem : csi.val )
      std::cout << elem << std::endl;

   cntWrp<std::vector<int>> cvi;

   cvi.addVal(2);
   cvi.addVal(7);
   cvi.addVal(5);

   std::cout << "vector:" << std::endl;

   for ( auto const elem : cvi.val )
      std::cout << elem << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

STL containers are not meant to be inherited. [They do not have virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647298/why-dont-stl-containers-have-virtual-destructors). It was discussed [having the containers as final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298450/are-c11-standard-containers-final), but it was not done because it would a breaking change.

So using composition is your best bet.

Comment: This is not correct, you are conflating inheritance and polymorphism. `protected` is a superset of of `public` and therefore non-polymorphic inheritance is a valid way to use *any* class (unless it's marked `final`).